# red frame like stripes in android screen

Tags: android, android-strictmode

we are developing an android device. its on android 4.4.2. My issue is that i am getting red frame like strip which occur at different frequencies. some come and go very fast. but some stay for some time.

i tried to remove the strict mode in developer option.
i tried to make `persist.sys.strictmode.visual` to 0 manually also by setprop.

But the red strips are killing my days.Please help me on this.
Dont put it as duplicate. Because everywhere the issue is solved with strictmode value to 0. But for me that solution is not helping..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but you can try this:
ADB into the device
(open command prompt and type "adb shell")

Then type the following commands

```
setprop persist.sys.strictmode.visual 0
setprop persist.sys.strictmode.disable 1
```

Once complete, restart the machine.  It worked for me using 5.0.0.

Comment: On Android 7.1.2 it is enough to set "setprop persist.sys.strictmode.disable 1"